# 1998 cherokee sport 4x4 hydraulic clutch problems

Tags: manual-transmission, jeep, 4wd, cherokee, clutch-hydraulics

The clutch in my 19
98 Jeep Cherokee four by four feels like its frozen.  The transmission will not go into any gear, including reverse. Whether the car is started, or not.

Comment: If the transmission won't shift when the engine is off, that's a tranny issue and not a clutch/hydraulic issue.